# Different values between `php -i` and `<?php phpinfo() ?>` ...?

Tags: php, linux, apache

When I use `php -i` at the CLI, I get `max_execution_time => 0 => 0`.
But if I use the browser to view `<?php phpinfo() ?>` I get `max_execution_time` having `Local value 30` and `Master value 30`.

How come there is a difference in value.

**Update**

- I have seen [2 php.ini files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871768/2-php-ini-files) and went away with idea that different values arises due to different files being accessed.
- The slight problem in this my own case is that both the CLI and Browser are pointing to `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` hence it is supposed to loading from the same file, so how come different values.

Comment: On second look ... @slapyo it seems there might be a slight difference, unless am the slow learner here ...

Comment: @markbaker ... is it different enough to warrant being unlocked