# PHP - Extensions are loaded, but not loaded in command line

Tags: php, entity-framework, sqlite, doctrine-orm

I've seen this happen with a number of extensions now. So I need the **php_pdo_pgsql** extension, and its definitely loaded. Heres the lines in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

[image]

The .dll files are in the ext directory. But from the command line:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Its not in there. Got the same problem with xdebug. Does anyone know whats happening here? Is it something to do with the environment variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 php.ini files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871768/2-php-ini-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there are 2 different `PHP configuration file(php.ini)` files. One for the CLI (Command line client) and one for server(APACHE).

You should use `-c` to specify path to `php.ini` file you want to use.

You can check details using `php --help` on cmd

Comment: I checked that out: `PS C:\wamp64\www\spider\chebi> php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)` so its loading the correct php.ini file. At least I think it is.

Comment: Whoops, I just found out that the php.ini file I had been editing through the WAMP menu, is actually the one in the Apache folder. So you were right, thats the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution or maybe the problem: I did not restart php-fpm. My system was Centos 8, Apache 2, Php-fpm with Fast CGI.

Once I restarted php-fpm with the following command:

```
 sudo service php-fpm restart
```

The extension, which is in my case, ionCube Loader started working and I could see it loaded both from the command line and over the server.