# max_execution_time won't update

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I somehow can't change max_execution_time in the php.ini. It won't update even though I restarted the server.

It simply doesen't update this specific setting, but others seem to update fine.

info.php says max_execution_time = 30 (default). But when I execute

```
php -i | grep max_execution_time
```

it outputs

```
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

Running Apache version 2.4.34 on Ubuntu with php 7.2

I have tried everything, but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Im really stuck here, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Might be worth looking into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871768/2-php-ini-files

Comment: Did you change both php.ini files? In Ubuntu I believe apache and CLI have different php.ini

Comment: Well, that was it. I only changed it in CLI. Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 php.ini files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871768/2-php-ini-files)