# Ext News adding one extra day to specified publish date

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

Using TYPO3 v8.7.27
Ext News v6.3.0

Just upgraded a site from TYPO3 v7 and News v5.

When I create a News story and set the publish date, the correct value is stored in the database. When I access the record, the correct date value is still present.

However, the News Story only becomes visible/published in the front end *exactly* one day after the specified publish date.

I checked the server and the correct date and time are set along with the correct time zone.

When I hover over the news record in the backend (News Administration) it now says "{todays date} 1 Days" somewhere, its adding +1 day to the publish date.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks again.

Tom

Comment: "<f:format.date format="Y" base="{todays date}">+1 day</f:format.date>"  search for something like this in code? Then change it. Maybe it will not work, we need to see your code really for a good answer :)

Comment: I haven't written any code - the {todays date} +1 is being shown in the News Administration panel in the backend.

Comment: Just an important sidenote: the php used by apache/nginx and the cli php are different and both can ahve a different config. See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871768/2-php-ini-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server datetime was not set to daylight savings.